# PrimeFaces' oncomplete attribute in JSF <h:commandButton>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I didn't find an `oncomplete` attribute available in some tags in PrimeFaces within a standard JSF `<h:commandButton>`.

How can I get oncomplete-like functionality while using `<h:commandButton>`?

Comment: AJAX or non-AJAX request?

Comment: I would be great to know in both case but i am looking for non ajax

Comment: @Downvoter please care to comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since primefaces `oncomplete` is equivalent to plain JSF `success` event (for more details take a look at [this answer comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17314549/617373) , you should use the `success` event in the following way:

Inline solution

```
<h:commandButton id="someId" action="#{myBean.myAction}">
    <f:ajax onevent="function(data) { if (data.status === 'success') { alert('complete'); }"
        render="whatevet"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

Another cleaner solution would be to use js function

```
<h:commandButton id="someId" action="#{myBean.myAction}">
    <f:ajax onevent="myJsFunction"
        render="whatevet"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

In your js file add

```
function myJsFunction(data) {
    if (data.status === 'success') {
         alert('complete');
    }
}
```

---

In case you are looking for a way to detect the completion of non ajax submit you can adopt the following idea from here [Detecting the File Download Dialog In the Browser](http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser)

---

The easiest solution would be to use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// check if some condition is meet and do something...
});
```

Comment: +1 for the great solution but I wont accept because I am looking for non ajax request.Please guide in case of non ajax How can I handle this?

Comment: @despicable In case of non-AJAX request your page will be reloaded, so except initial page opening it is page onload event.

Comment: why don't we use the oncomplete functionality of f:ajax here?

Comment: @ethanjyx, there is no `oncomplete` attribute in `f:ajax`