# How to show a popup when page navigation does not happen

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf, popup

I have a web page in jsp extension , which is built using jsf. There are command links for some user ids, i.e. every user id is a command link. When a user id is clicked, it goes to another page, where some action can be done.

```xhtml
<h:commandLink value="#{user.userId}" rendered="#{bean.myName == 'ID1'}"  action="#{bean.userIdHasBeenSelected}" immediate="true"/>
```

Now if the action returns a string called "notDone", i want to show an alert pop up in the jsp and the page will not be navigated and will remain in the same page. But , if the action returns the afore mentioned string , the page will just be not navigated..it will not be reloaded or refreshed..then how can i use window.onload here ?

If not window.onload , then is there any other way of doing it ? One point to be remembered is that, the action is evaluated at java side.

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: you could add a script let?

Comment: Use onComplete callback. This can also be used with <h:commandLink> See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805825/primefaces-oncomplete-attribute-in-jsf-hcommandbutton

Comment: If you return an `String` you're telling JSF to perform a navigation, then the page will be reloaded. That will just not work. You need to return an empty `String` or `null` in that case to properly handle it.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes, that is what I had done, just after I posted the question and this seems to be a fair solution nonetheless .

Comment: Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Please do, only can then i accept it .