# JSF onevent or js depending on ajax listener result

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, listener

I need ideas to solve next situation.

I have a commandButton with ajax that invokes a listener with a boolean method, something like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Add">
    <f:ajax listener="#{shoppingCartBean.makeReservation(devicesBean.device)}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If the listener returns true, its because device is correctly reserved, everything works fine and I need to redirect to another url with a location.href js function.

If the listener returns false, I need that a js alert will be shown with a "Sorry, no device stock bla bla bla".

How can I manage that? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery:

```
<h:commandButton id="someId" action="#{myBean.myAction}">
       <f:ajax onevent="myJsFunction"   render="whatevet"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
function myJsFunction(data) {
   if (data.status === 'success') {
     alert('complete');
   }
}
```

for more detail, see this track https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806084/3056912

Comment: But the problem is the js function needs the listener (in my case) or the action (in yours) boolean result to know what to do... I don't know if you understand what I mean. In your example, if myBean.myAction returns true, the myJsFunction needs this result to alert or do another thing...

Comment: hmm, why dont you use navigation rule? 
if true you do the redirect. If not you set a boolean and rerender the popup component based on the boolean...

Comment: Its because of pretty-faces I need to redirect with an URL not with an xhtml resource.... but thx.

Comment: hmmm :/

If you use primefaces you can use onComplete. 

`<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{userController.saveUser}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" /> `

Comment: hehe I think u haven't readed it correctly, not prime, PRETTY-FACES, for urls :)

Comment: Yeah... but if you have primeface in your project... you can use oncomplete attribute to do what you want...

I think your problem is more logical than a limitation by jsf/pretty-faces. 

Buuuut... i tried :D

Comment: Thx 4 everything, but unfortunately I can't use PF in this project... :(

Comment: :( 

Man take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3718859/3056912

maybe you can use this with my suggestion bellow to do your redirect with pretty-faces, no? :}